# What can I use to lubricate electrical contacts?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I've been replacing lots of 2 pin MR-16 halogen bulbs and have been having a very difficult time inserting them into the sockets.  I've also lost few pins removing the old bulbs.

Is there anything I can use to lubricate the pins and socket to make this easier?  I've read about people using everything from WD40, Vaseline, lithium grease and Silone grease.

[image: MR16]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest the use of a `dielectric grease'. In particular, look for one compatible with high temperature, which are often made out of silicone. The grease can be ordered online, but would also be available at many auto-parts stores.

One requirement of this application is that the lubricant must not be electrically conductive. If a conductive lubricant is used, it would be a fire hazard. Dielectric means that it wouldn't conduct electricity.

Comment: if the lubricant is not conductive, and it is all over the pins, wouldn't that prevent it from working?

Comment: The idea is that the pin will make metal->metal contact with the contact. The grease will be thin enough (or non-existant) at the interface that it won't impede current flow. That said, you don't want to use too much grease, either.